# Scala.js referencing using this

Tags: highcharts, scala.js

I'm using scala.js (v0.6.13) with the Highcharts facade, and I have run into a roadblock trying to access some variables that I would normally access in javascript using 'this' and 'chart'. Here's an example:

coffeescript:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: true,
  positioner: (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) ->
    return { x: chart.plotWidth - labelWidth + chart.plotLeft, y: 17 }
  formatter: () ->
    x = this.x
    point = this.points.find (p) -> x == p.x
    ...
```

My question is how do I access "this.x" and "chart.plotWidth" in my formatter and positioner functions in scala.js? Here's my scala code thus far:

```
override val tooltip: Cfg[Tooltip] = Tooltip(
  formatter = { () =>
    "what?"
  }: js.Function0[String],
  positioner = { (labelWidth: Any, labelHeight: Any, point: Object) =>
    js.Dynamic.literal(
      x = labelWidth,
      y = 17)
  }: js.Function3[Any, Any, Object, Object]
)
```

edit: chart pertains to a highchart chart.

Comment: You might want to point out that your original snippet is written in CoffeeScript rather than JavaScript, so that Scala.js readers not familiar with CoffeeScript don't get utterly confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `js.ThisFunctionN` to explicitly capture the special `this` of JavaScript as a normal parameter in Scala.js.

```
positioner = { (thiz: js.Dynamic, labelWidth: Any, labelHeight: Any, point: Object) =>
  // here the variable `thiz` holds what would be `this` in JS
  ...
}: js.ThisFunction3[js.Dynamic, Any, Any, Object, Object]
```

When converting a Scala anonymous function to a `js.ThisFunction`, the `this` argument is passed in as the first parameter.

See https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/types.html for more details.

For `chart`, your question does not give enough context to know what `chart` is in your CoffeeScript code. But I guess just using `chart` in Scala.js will do whatever the original code does.

Comment: Thanks, for the direction!